# Angular Compiler not reporting missing property in template

Tags: angular

The Angular AOT compiler does not fail when using a non existing property in a template if the usage is wrapped in an `*ngIf` directive.

E.g. in this example, `custom` does not have a property `property` defined:

```
<div *ngIf="condition">
  {{ custom.property }}
</div>
```

Why does the Angular compiler not fail on this code?
Is there a way to instrument it to do so?

And just for clarification, it fails with this code as expected:

```
<div>
  {{ custom.property }}
</div>
```

I'm currently thinking of creating a custom lint script that would remove all `*ngIf`s from the code and do an AOT build to check that all properties do exist. Is that a valid idea? And if so, why do I have to do this in the first place?

I'm using Angular 5, but I think it doesn't work in newer versions either.

I found that the Angular Language service is able to report these errors (in VS Code or IntelliJ IDEA). So it should be possible.

Comment: Are you running with --prod  flag?

Comment: You can dynamically add or delete properties, and most IDEs won't be able to check for these. There are some properties (added by `Object.defineProperty` for instance) that you can't check for in an AOT build. I don't think removing these is necessary. It seems a bit opinionated - what happens to the properties not wrapped in an `*ngIf` directive? Angular templating has an "safe navigation operator" syntax similar to Swift's optionals. You can rewrite your templates to use `custom?.property`, see https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: My opinion: javascript itself is a versatile language, it's the developer's responsibility to ensure the variables are accessible. Angular provides a safe navigation operator to help, but it's the programmer's responsibility nevertheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular actually provides this feature, but it's not turned on by default for whatever reason.

Adding the following code to `tsconfig.json` enables a full template type check:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
}
```

But beware, this does not in fact do a "full" type check. It still skips over complex structural constructs. But in Ivy this will apparently be a feature that the compiler is able to do a proper "full" template type check.