# Enable full template type-checking in Angular application

Tags: angular

Is there a way, by using the Angular Compiler, to enable full template type-checking? I don't see it as an option listed [here](https://angular.io/cli/build) but I was curious if there was another way to enable it.

Comment: If you use VSC as your editor, the Angular Language Service extension does pretty much that

Comment: VSC will give me a warning, but will the build fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Compiler not reporting missing property in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895483/angular-compiler-not-reporting-missing-property-in-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use AOT compilation, you can control how your application is
>   compiled by specifying template compiler options in the tsconfig.json

Add angularCompilerOptions object with fullTemplateTypeCheck property in tsconfig.json

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
      "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
      "preserveWhitespaces": true,
                ...
    }
```

[For More Info](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the argument `noUnusedLocals: true` and `noUnusedParameters: true` to your tsconfig.json under `compilerOptions`.

Comment: Hmm, I meant to check the `.html` for any unused references in the components' `.ts` file.

Comment: Even still, this will only check for unused locals and parameters inside of my `.ts`. Consider the case where I have an unused `private` property that is actually referenced inside of my `.html`.