# Angular compiler does not report template error but IntelliJ does

Tags: angular, typescript

I know there's a similar question here: [Angular Compiler not reporting missing property in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895483/angular-compiler-not-reporting-missing-property-in-template)

But I already have set `strictTemplates: true` in my tsconfig.json:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

// tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
}

// angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "",
  "projects": {
    "myProject": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              ...
              "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.json",
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "designa-client:build",
            "host": "0.0.0.0"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "designa-client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
}
```

I thought with `strictTemplates` set to `true` all template errors should be set to true, but somehow the Angular compiler still lets the following template through:

```html
<pmt-placed-products-list
  [products]="products"
></pmt-placed-products-list>
```

Whereas IntelliJ (**correctly!!**) complains that there is no `@Input` property `products`:

[image]

**There really is an error in the template which IntelliJ detects, but the Angular compiler doesn't!** I'm using Angular 11 btw, so Ivy should be the default compiler.

Comment: Sometimes the linter (IntelliJ) doesn't know everything about each component. I typically ignore linter errors if things work. The errors I really care about are from compiler or the console in the browser

Comment: That's not my question: the linter (IntelliJ) is actually right! There IS an error in the template, but the angular compiler does not detect it

Comment: Oh gotcha. Is there an error in the console output? I can't remember if the compiler will detect those errors or not.

Comment: same was happening for me, when I forgot to load a cdk module for some component. My IDE was displaying an error although I couldn't see anything reported by angular in console.